# Laravel Dusk auth issues with Laravel Passport

Tags: laravel, tdd, laravel-passport, laravel-dusk

Can't test applications with Laravel Dusk if the app uses Laravel Passport for authentication. It's always 404 and if you stop the test with `->stop()` it starts working.

The app is located: `localhost:3000`
and all requests are proxied to `api.example.test`

I've tried to authenticate the user inside the test:

```php
$this->actingAs(User::find(1), 'api');
$browser->loginAs(User::find(1));
Passport::actingAs($this->user);
```

But still the same.

That's not the only problem, I think the main issue is also that I can't log in with Dusk by filling out the form and click "login"

```
$browser->visit('/login')
   ->type('@email', 'john@doe.com')
   ->type('@password', 'password')
   ->click('@login-button')
   ->waitForLocation('/');
```

But again, if you stop the test with `->stop()` you can manually click the button and it will log you in.

Is Laravel Dusk useless if your app does not use basic auth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The problem was that my Dusk `.env` file had `APP_URL=localhost:3000` where the front-end is located, but my APIs `.env` file had `APP_URL=api.exmaple.com` and that's why in my `AuthController`, I issued the token from `env('APP_URL').'/oauth/token'` <- which resulted in Dusk env to `localhost:3000/oauth/token` which is ofc 404

I changed that to `env('API_URL')` and added that value to my both `.env` files.